# Running wine apps through a launcher and docker in 18.04

Tags: gnome, wine, launcher, docker

I had no problems doing this in Unity by the way. The problem started with the 18.04 when I started using the built in Gnome docker.

I have three windows apps that I have the user to run through clicking an icon. The launcher I created successfully runs a script with the following content:

```
export LANG=sl.SI.utf8 && wine "somepath/asp.exe"
```

I don't think the actual content of the script is a problem however I can only add launcher links with icons to the desktop area only and NOT the dock.
If I run the application adding it to favourites does not work. When the app is opened a 
[default icon appears in the dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKo1w.png)
Clicking add to favourites does keep that icon there but it does not work when clicked. I get the hour glass for a few seconds and then nothing happens.

I have tried manually creating .desktop files in "~/.local/share/applications". Does not seem applicable for the Gnome dock though.

Is this a bug/limitation in Gnome?

Comment: Yes, I might have not been specific on the terminology but I will excuse myself due to the change to Gnome. I think they call it the Gnome dock. I found an article saying that the nautilus will e deprecating running binary apps directly with double clicking but I don't think this applies in this problem.

Comment: If you sure that you mean Gnome Dock, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1104439/edit). Comments are often overlooked by the folks who know the answers.